# Collapsible Hierarchy Select List

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I'm looking for a combination between a standard select list and [Taxonomy Term Reference Tree Widget](https://www.drupal.org/project/term_reference_tree).

I want a select list that has expandable and collapsible parent terms so it's easy to navigate - sure, there are options using shs, etc. but they take up a bit of space when I have five levels, and all I need is the child term from the deepest level to be recorded.

Alternatively, it would be ok to have something like shs that uses the same field when selecting each new level, rather than appending with a new select list each time.

Are there any solutions like this?

Comment: You might be able to pull some useful code from Taxonomy Manager, it has a good expanding tree system.

Comment: Thanks @Darvanen - trouble is, I'm a bit of a hack and have no idea how I'd go about it... :(